# What do I use instead of ForiegnKey relationship for multi-db relation

Tags: django, django-models

I need to provide my users a list of choices from a model which is stored in a separate legacy database. Foreign keys aren't supported in django multi-db setups. The ideal choice would be to use a foreign key, but since thats not possible I need to some up with something else.

So instead I created an IntegerField on the other database and tried using choices to get a list of available options.

```
class OtherDBTable(models.Model):
    client = models.IntegerField(max_length=20, choices=Client.objects.values_list('id','name'))
```

the problem I'm having is that the choices seem to get populated once but never refreshed. How do I ensure that whenever the client list changes that those newest options area available to pick.

Comment: Choices would only be calculated once when you start the server. I'm not sure how to alter model attributes dynamically but you can definitely dynamically create choices in a django form easily by setting `self.fields['field'].choices = whatever` in the form `__init__` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was really looking for was a way that I could simulate the behavior of a Foreign key field, at least as far as matching up ID's go.

There wasn't a clear way to do this, since it doesn't seem like you can actually specify an additional field when you instantiate a model (you can with forms, easily)

In any case to deal with the problem, since the database is MySQL based, I ended up creating views from the tables I needed in the other database.

Answer (score 0):

To build on @Yuji's answer - if you do `self.fields['field'].choices = whatever` in the model's `__init__`, `whatever` can be any iterable.

This means you can inherit from `iterable`, and have that object interface to your legacy database, or you can use a generator function (in case you are unfamiliar, look up the `yield` keyword).

Answer (score -2):

Citing a Django's [manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/):

> Finally, note that choices can be any iterable object -- not necessarily a list or tuple. **This lets you construct choices dynamically**. But if you find yourself hacking choices to be dynamic, **you're probably better off using a proper database table with a ForeignKey**. choices is meant for static data that doesn't change much, if ever.

Why dont you want just export data from the legacy database and to import it into the new one? This could be done periodically, if the legacy database still in use.

Comment: this seems like a hackish solution. I don't want to have two sets of data to keep in sync since data is added to the other database periodically.